# Search for and replace values in a KML file

Tags: php, simplexml, kml

I'm very new to php so go easy on me.

I'm trying to search through a KML file for latitude and longitude values, then replace them with user inputted lat/long values. The problem I'm having is actually searching through the KML file to find the specific lat/long values to be replaced.

**KML**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2" xmlns:gx="http://www.google.com/kml/ext/2.2" xmlns:kml="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
<Folder>
    <name>Folder-Name</name>
    <open>1</open>
    <gx:Tour>
        <name class="name">Tour-Name</name>
        <gx:Playlist>
            <gx:FlyTo>
                <LookAt>
                    <gx:horizFov>100</gx:horizFov>
                    <longitude class="lookat-long">33.33333</longitude>
                    <latitude class="lookat-lat">-111.11111</latitude>
                    <altitude>0</altitude>
                    <heading>0</heading>
                    <tilt>60</tilt>
                    <range>100</range>
                    <altitudeMode>relativeToGround</altitudeMode>
                </LookAt>
            </gx:FlyTo>
        </gx:Playlist>
    </gx:Tour>
</Folder>
</kml>
```

I need to replace "33.33333" and "-111.11111" with user inputted values. I have tried using SimpleXML, but it does not recognize the `gx:` part of the tag, since that is KML specific, and not part of XML. So when I try this code:

```
<?php
    $xml = simplexml_load_file('my_kml_file');
    print_r($xml)
?>
```

I get this output:

```
SimpleXMLElement Object ( [Folder] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [name] => Temporary Places [open] => 0 ) )
```

It just stops at `<open>` because it doesn't recognize the rest. I have spent hours upon hours trying to figure out how to best do this and I just can't. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the xpath method to get the namespaced node like so:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file('my_kml_file');
$xml->xpath('//gx:Tour/gx:Playlist/gx:FlyTo')[0]->LookAt->longitude = 'newValue';
$xml->xpath('//gx:Tour/gx:Playlist/gx:FlyTo')[0]->LookAt->latitude = 'newValue';
print_r($xml->asXml());
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2" xmlns:gx="http://www.google.com/kml/ext/2.2" xmlns:kml="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
<Folder>
    <name>Folder-Name</name>
    <open>1</open>
    <gx:Tour>
        <name class="name">Tour-Name</name>
        <gx:Playlist>
            <gx:FlyTo>
                <LookAt>
                    <gx:horizFov>100</gx:horizFov>
                    <longitude class="lookat-long">newValue</longitude>
                    <latitude class="lookat-lat">newValue</latitude>
                    <altitude>0</altitude>
                    <heading>0</heading>
                    <tilt>60</tilt>
                    <range>100</range>
                    <altitudeMode>relativeToGround</altitudeMode>
                </LookAt>
            </gx:FlyTo>
        </gx:Playlist>
    </gx:Tour>
</Folder>
</kml>
```

Comment: That's definitely a step in the right direction, but now how do I edit only the lat/long values from that?

Comment: @TeaBoneJones Updated my answer. There are better ways of handling this but I think this gives you the right idea on how to do this :)